# what is the meaning of differentiating this equation with respect to a third variable?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a equation $y= x^{-1/2}$. Both $x$ and $y$ are also a function of third variable, $t$. If I differentiate this equation wrt $t$, I get:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4mYXm.png)

If $(x_0, y_0)$ are the initial values, and $(x_1, y_1)$ are the final values, what does this $x$ (of $x^{-3/2}$) represent in this new equation? Does this $x$ represent the initial value ($x_0$) or the final value ($x_1$)?

Answer (score 1):

This simply means that at any point $(x_0,y_0,t_0)$ the rate of change of $y$ with respect to $t$ - $\frac{\delta y}{\delta t}$ - is equal to the value of $-\frac{1}{2}x_0^{-3/2}$ multiplied by the rate of change of $x$ with respect to $t$ - $\frac{\delta x}{\delta t}$ - where each of the rates of change are evaluated where $t=t_0$.

Answer (score 0):

I must first clarify that the initial and final points will explicitly be $t_0$ and $t_1$. So, the values of the functions $x=x(t)$ and $y=y(t)$ at the points $t_0$ and $t_1$ will be $(x_0(t_0), y_0 (t_0) )$ and $(x_1(t_1), y_1 (t_1) )$.

The term $x^{-3/2}$ is neither initial value nor final value, It is the part of the function (the first derivative) that indicates the relation between the change of the function $y(t)$ with respect to $t$, which is $\partial y / \partial t$, to the change of the function $x(t)$ with respect to $t$, which is $\partial x / \partial t$.

Therefore, the term $-\frac{-1}{2} x^{\frac{-3}{2}}$ is the ratio $\frac{\partial y / \partial t}{\partial x / \partial t}$, and it varies at every point including the initial and final points $t$.